# Not displaying div using while loop

Tags: php, html, css

The below is a simple code for generating div using while loop, but its not working?

Its not very complex just basic HTML but still its not displaying 5 div?
Actually not even single div is displayed!?

```
<?php 
$i=1;
while($i==5)
{
echo "<div class='data_block'></div>";  
$i++;   
}
?>
```

css:

```
.data_block
{
    background-color: #7E81A0;
    width:95%;
    height:30%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: Change `==` to `<` Doh

Comment: wow it worked so silly! why '==' dont work in php?

Comment: it does but **think about it**

Comment: wait for the answers now...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while($i==5)
```

Is checking if `$i` is equal to `5`

The line above sets `$i` to `1`

Therefore it never runs.

You want something like this:

```
while($i<5)
```

---

Comment: Thanks! I will mark you answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
   for($i=0; $i<5; $i++){
      echo "<div class='data_block'></div>";    
   }
?>
```

---

Comment: Why should it be changed to a badly coded `for` loop?